# How can I use string variables in a serialized text field of Unity?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a c# script attached to a prefab. It has a dialogue list of strings that I prefer to write through the serializable fields function of unity. The script has a stored string variable 'charactername' that contains the name of the player. The problem is that at times, I am required to fetch the character name to place in the dialogue string. Imagine if there's a character who is looking through your id card and goes "Oh, so your name is XYZ".
I can't hardcode the dialogues in the script as it's a prefab and all the NPCs are using the same prefab with different dialogue lists. Someone told me to have a script on the TextMeshPro element that deletes my own small codes like /p and replaces it with the player name. But I feel like it's a dirty method of doing things. Is there a better way?

To clarify, my problem is that I need a way of using strings by their variable names in the Serialized Field of a string in the unity editor's inspector. So, while my code contains a variable named 'characterName', the place where I want to use its value is a rectangular text box in the unity editor's inspector panel under the attached script itself.

Comment: You can create custom UI for serialized fields in the Unity editor using custom inspectors

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then you can use the [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) like the one below.

```
string characterName = "XYZ";
string dialogue = $"Oh, so your name is {characterName}.";
```

You can also use the `string.Format` method or you could use a place holder in your original string and then use string `Replace` method to replace it by the `characterName`.

Comment: My apologies if I didn't explain my problem correctly. I tried using the {[variablename]} in the serialized field but it doesn't work. 
To clarify, my problem is that I need a way of using strings by their variable names in the Serialized Field of a string in the unity editor's inspector itself. So, while my code contains a variable named 'characterName', the place where I want to use its value is a rectangular text box in the unity editor's inspector panel under the attached script itself. 

Again thanks for such a quick reply and sorry for bothering again. I hope you're having a good day.